# I tried creating an area calculator, it keeps stating invalid syntax for a correct code

Tags: python, calculator

I started a project in Codeacademy to create an area calculator. However the code `elif option == "T":` keeps producing syntax error. I looked at the solution but it looks exactly the same. Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance.

I've tried changing indentation and spacing and changing it from double quotes to single quotes. I even copied and pasted the solution but it still doesn't work.

```
# it calculates area of circle and triangle
print"Calculator, Ready!"
option = raw_input("What shape. Enter C for Circle or T for triangle: ")
if option == "C":
  radius = float(raw_input(" What is the radius: "))
area = 3.14159 * radius ** 2
print area

elif option == 'T':
  base = float(raw_input("Base: "))
  height = float(raw_input("Height: "))
area = .5 * base * height
print area
```

Comment: It's not valid to create an `if` block, outdent the code, and then use an `elif` block. All content under the `if` must be indented if you want to use `elif` after it.

Answer (score 0):

In Pythhon, a `elif` statement can only follow a `elif` or `if` statement, but in your code, it follows a print.

You may indent or remove the two following lines:

```
area = 3.14159 * radius ** 2
print area
```

My understanding of your code makes me propose you this solution:

```
# ==========================================
# It calculates area of circle and triangle

# A good practice is to initialise all your variable at the begining
option = None
radius = None
area = None
base = None
height = None

print("Calculator, Ready!")
option = raw_input("What shape. Enter C for Circle or T for triangle: ")

if option == "C":
  radius = float(raw_input(" What is the radius: "))
  area = 3.14159 * radius ** 2
elif option == 'T':
  base = float(raw_input("Base: "))
  height = float(raw_input("Height: "))
  area = .5 * base * height

print ("The calculated area is: {}".format(area))
```

Comment: The `area` line should be indented, not removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the area calculations since they're part of the `if` and `elif` blocks. You're getting a syntax error because an `elif` statement must follow an `if` block.

Also since you're doing `print area` in both cases, you only need to write it once.

The important bits fixed:

```
if option == "C":
  radius = float(raw_input(" What is the radius: "))
  area = 3.14159 * radius ** 2
elif option == 'T':
  base = float(raw_input("Base: "))
  height = float(raw_input("Height: "))
  area = .5 * base * height
print area
```